# Jasper missing word when page breaks

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a little problem when I export the jasper result in PDF.
I use the following configuration for the font i use (Century Gothic):
[image]

I also configured the font for bold/italic/bold italic.

Anyway when I see the preview in jasper i have the following result for my document:
[image]

You can see that at the end of the first page there is the word "uw" present.
But when i export the PDF, i have the following result:
[image]
Actually, the word "uw" is no more at the end of the first page, neither at the beginning of the second page, it has disappeared.

Have you an idea about the problem?

I have checked on the web, this problem seems to be related to a bad font configuration, but in my case i don't think this is the problem, since the PDF font match visually with the font in Jasper preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little bit guessing need to see your .jrxml (it would be good to included in question) but this could be the problem.

Your textfield is to small to show all text with the font you are using in pdf, its getting truncated away by jasper report on export

Set `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` on the `textField`

or do it larger

**NOTES ON isStretchWithOverflow**

> Stretching elements in height can be managed very well, due to the section split facility: with very few exceptions **(ie the column and page footers)**, report sections can also stretch beyond the initial specified height, and split onto next page (see the spliType attribute in the  element).
>
> Text fields with delayed evaluation do not stretch to acquire all the expression’s content. This is because the text element height is calculated when the report section is generated, and even if the engine comes back later with the text content of the text field, the element height will not adapt, because this would ruin the already created layout.
>   When filling report templates horizontally, dynamic text fields inside the detail section do not stretch to their entire text content, because this might cause misalignment on the horizontal axis of subsequent detail sections. The detail band actually behaves the same as the page and column footers, preserving its declared height when horizontal filling is used.

So in page and column footers the `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` will only work as high as the band height.

Comment: Like you said, i tried to make the textfield more larger: from 165.80 mm to 167.92 mm, and now the text appears in the pdf export. But my textfield had isStretchWithOverflow="true", so i supposed it was enough. Anyway how can we be sure that the new size 167.92 mm, is enough for all the possible cases (supposing we don't know what the text in input will look like?)

Comment: Well it will probably stretch, but it ends out of page (which band are you using the footer?), I suggest that you make it very high and align text to the bottom....  work around ; )

Comment: See edit, you can not stretch out of band height if you are using column or page footer, do the work around or switch band...

Comment: Actually my report (main report) has only one band "Detail 1", in this band i have 4 textFields on the top, and 6 subreports on the bottom. Each subreport has 2/3 textfields inside. The text creating the issue was inside one of the subreports. All the textfields and the subreports are in "Float". The split type inside the subreports are defined as "Immediate", in order to avoid white space happening with other split definitions.

Comment: By switching band, do you mean to use multiple Detail bands instead of putting all the subreports inside one Detail band?

Comment: No I was thinking you had it in the footer band..., you have fill horizontally or vertically?.., if vertically and you have no strange tags on the subreport, I'm getting at a dead end...